Does Flutter Listener class consume much resource
I am trying to refresh api token when it expires on one module of the app, one of the approach I think of is wrapping the widgets in a flutter Listener class and get user event, compare the last token time with current.
The project is already heavy on it own and we are trying not to use unnecessary library in the project
My question is does Flutter Listener consume much resource or it is optimised?
Any advice on better way to approach this?
Thanks

Depends on how often events happens, and how long the callback takes to run.  I would hope that would be obvious.  There's nearly zero overhead in between.

Thank you @RandalSchwartz. event only happen when user open the app and goes to the app module...

Also many api event is called when the module page. but if token fails, all the api fails.. we trying to optimise on not having to wait till the api failed before refreshing the token
